# DateTime.TryParse for only a Time parameter?

Tags: c#

I am writing a service that calls a method at 4pm and 5am. I would like to keep these times from being hard coded and so I would like to have put them in my appconfig.

Here is the code I have:

```
public bool CheckTime() 
        {
            DateTime startTime;
            DateTime endTime; 

            DateTime.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessingStartTime"], out startTime);
            DateTime.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessingEndTime"], out endTime);

            if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Equals(startTime) || DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Equals(endTime))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

But, since I only want to store the time as a string (something as easy as "4:00pm") how do I parse and encapsulate JUST the time in a DateTime object? Or is there another object? I don't care about the date, it just has to be M-F of any given week of any given year.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) with an appropriate format string, and then ignore the date. There's no nice encapsulation for "just a time" in .NET. However, there's an alternative - I've been working hard on [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which has the `LocalTime` type for just this purpose:

```
// "Traditional" way
LocalTime time;
if (LocalTime.TryParseExact(text, "h:mmtt", out time))
{
    ...
}

// Preferred way

private static readonly LocalTimePattern TimePattern = 
    LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("h:mmtt");
...

ParseResult<LocalTime> parseResult = TimePattern.Parse(text);
if (parseResult.Success)
{
    LocalTime time = parseResult.Value;
    ...
}
```

Two side-notes:

- It's almost *never* appropriate to ignore the return value from `DateTime.TryParse` (or any other `TryParse` method) - do you really want to use `DateTime.MinValue` if there's a problem with the data? There *are* cases where the default value is appropriate, but they're pretty rare
- Please try to avoid code of the form:

  ```
  if (condition)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
  ```

  This is much more clearly written as:

  ```
  return condition;
  ```

Comment: I just saw the wiki - slick! Its nice to know I am not the only one that sees this "shortcoming" with the DateTime class in .Net. I hope my situation is a good reminder (use-case) of why we need projects like Noda Time. Thanks and keep it up!

Comment: @fullNelson: I think it's likely to be more of a relief for *me* that I'm not alone in thinking it's a gap... given the time I've spent on it :)

Comment: Regarding the code correction, are you saying I should state my condition logic inline and let the evaluation of that logic return true or false implicitly?

Comment: @fullNelson: I'm saying that you've already got an expression which evaluates to `true` or `false`, which you're using as the `if` condition... why bother using an `if` when you can just return that value directly?

Comment: Looks like the NodaTime API has changed. LocalTime.TryParseExact is no FYI: longer valid.

Comment: @ComeIn: Where do you see any reference to `LocalTime.TryParseExact`? You call `Parse` on a `LocalTimePattern`, and that's very much still valid.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a hard time doing the tryparse (even w/ TryParseExact) so I wrote a regex:

```
Regex checkTime = new Regex(@"^(?i)(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?( AM| PM)?$");
```

And you can validate your time with this:

```
checkTime.IsMatch(str);
```

This will work for these format (case insensitive):

- 08:09:00 AM
- 08:09 AM
- 8:30 AM
- 8:30:59

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/7XcNFC/2)

Hope this helps